# Phalcon - ORM Updating with save cause duplicate entries

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm fighting with a problem for a considerable time, and I can't find a nice way to fix my issue.

Let's say I have two tables:

`uses (id, name)`

`uses_phone (id, user_id, phone)`

Supposing I have created a `users (1, 'Mary')` and her phones `users_phones (1, 1, '123') (2, 1, '333')`

If I want to update Mary, to change her name to "Maria":

The `save()` method will NOT delete the actual records in `users_phone`, but will `insert` new entries, and then I will have:

`1, 1, 123
2, 1, 333
3, 1, 123
4, 1, 333`

Which is the best way to solve this issue? I'm a bit confused. I like using Model instead PHQL (I like it too, but Models with ORM seems quie magic).

**EDIT: Add code**

I have updated my post to include the model relationships and a simplified version of my controller

**Model** Relationships:

```
class Users {
  ...
  $this->hasMany('xid', 'UsersTelephones', 'xid_user', ['alias' => 'UsersTelephones']);
  ...
}

class UsersTelephones { 
   ...
   $this->belongsTo('xid_user', '\Users', 'xid', ['alias' => 'Users']);
   ...
}
```

(very simplified) **Controller** code:

```
function update($xid) {
   ...
   $user = Users::findFirstByXid($xid);
   // $user->email = "..";

   $user_tfs = array();
   for ($i=0;$i<count($tfs_array);$i++)
   {
      $user_tfs[$i] = new UsersTelephones();
      $user_tfs[$i]->tf_number = $tfs_array[$i];
   }
   $user->UsersTelephones = $user_tfs;

   // ...

   $user->save()
}
```

Thanks for reading and please forgive my bad English.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code used to save records? Also be sure to check your model afterSave() or other similar event methods.

Comment: Also, post any model association definitions that you have.

Comment: Thanks both for commenting, I have updated my question, please review it. Thank you!

Comment: Same here. Can't find the reason for this behaviour. I've disabled handling of relations on update/save completely. And when I want to store relations, I do not assign the object like `$user->phone = $phoneObject;` but assign numeric IDs directly, like `$user->phoneId = $phoneObject->getId();`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your controller code, I have a few suggestions:

1) First, from where `$tfs_array` comes from?

2) You might also want to add the existing telephone record's `id` to the `$user_tfs[$i]` object, like: `$user_tfs[$i]->id = $tfs_array[ID_OF_RECORD];` (you will need to add the record id to `$tfs_array`). This way, the ORM can interpret that the record already exists because the object has an `id` primary key.

3) Why do you want to iteratively add the `UsersTelephones` objects if all you want is to save the new name? You can go like:

```
$user = Users::findFirstByXid($xid);
$user->name = 'New Name';
$user->save();
```

4) You can also call the `$model->update()` method instead of `save()`.

Here are more links:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models#create-update-records
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models#create-update-with-confidence
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/db-models-relationships#updating-related-records

Comment: Hello! `$tfs_array` is just a vector of string(s) which comes from previous validations/etc. The issue is that I get a new `$tfs_array` from `POST`, how would assigning an ID work if I delete one? (and I am editing everything, because users have many fields [both in users and other tables] and would like to avoid checking for differences :/)

Comment: `Users::findFirstByXid($xid);` should also get the telephone records associated with that user.

Comment: how can I **delete/update** the current telephones? I don't follow how I can delete them if assigning an empty array doesn't

Comment: Hmm, I think I will try `update()` when I have a bit of time, thanks for answering, I upvoted.

When I test it I will check the issue as solved :-)